# Where do you assign the .ico file to display for a program's Unisntall (in Add/Remove programs) in Windows?

Tags: windows, uninstallation, addremoveprograms

I want to assign an icon to display next to my app's Uninstaller in the Windows Add/Remove programs.

I assume that would be in the Registry setting for the uninstaller, but I don' see an obvious place to assign that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\YourProgramName\DisplayIcon`

`DisplayIcon` should be a `REG_SZ` key and should give the absolute path of the icon file to use.